# how to check the time using if statement and for loop for my dataframe

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, jupyter

here is my statement in jupyter notebook
##check time frame to fill shift feature

```
 t2=dfOriginal['From']
time1=np.datetime64('1900-01-01T07:00:00')
time2=np.datetime64('1900-01-01T15:00:00')
time3=np.datetime64('1900-01-01T23:00:00')
for index in dfOriginal.iterrows():{
    if(t2>=time1 & t2 <time2):
    }
```

example of what i have in From column '1900-01-01T07:00:00'
From data type is datetime64[ns]

i get this error

```
 File "<ipython-input-64-2685fa7977d0>", line 7
 if(t2>=time1 & t2 <time2):
 SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why is the `if expression in `{}`?  And lacking any body?

Comment: i'm not sure how to write this and that why i'm asking for a help, syntax error does not show what is the right syntax